# I am trying to connect to Firebase and I have followed all the steps I get these errors. I searched a lot here and found nothing

Tags: android, firebase

[image]classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'

androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'
```

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

```
* What went wrong:
```

A problem occurred configuring root project 'Car shop'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
>   Could not resolve com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3.
>        Required by:
>            project :
>   Could not resolve com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3.
>   Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/4.3.3/google-services-4.3.3.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/4.3.3/google-services-4.3.3.pom'.
>   Connect to 10.147.1.1:3128 [/10.147.1.1] failed: Connection timed out: connect
>   Could not resolve com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3.
>   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/gms/google-services/4.3.3/google-services-4.3.3.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/gms/google-services/4.3.3/google-services-4.3.3.pom'.
>   Connect to 10.147.1.1:3128 [/10.147.1.1] failed: Connection timed out: connect

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 12s
ERROR: Connection timed out: connect

Answer (score 0):

Add the google maven repository to your project by adding `google()` to the `build.gradle` file in root folder of your project (not in the sub-folders for the modules).

It should then look like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Existing with a verb now showing an illustration of the problem